# Do I need to take care of producer-consumer rate-matching when using Akka 1.3's actors?

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka, actor

When using Akka 1.3, do I need to worry about what happens when the actors producing messages are producing them faster than than the actors consuming them can process?

Without any mechanism, in a long running process, the queue sizes would grow to consume all available memory.

[The doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/1.3.1/java/dispatchers.html#Default_dispatcher) says the default dispatcher is the ExecutorBasedEventDrivenDispatcher.

This dispatcher has five queue configuration:

- Bounded LinkedBlockingQueue
- Unbounded LinkedBlockingQueue
- Bounded ArrayBlockingQueue
- Unbounded ArrayBlockingQueue
- SynchronousQueue

and four overload policies:

- CallerRuns
- Abort
- Discard
- DicardOldest

Is this the right mechanism to be looking at? If so, what are this dispatchers' default settings?

Answer (score 0):

The dispatcher has a task queue. This is unrelated to your problem. In fact, you want as many mailboxes to be enqueued as possible.

What you might be looking for is: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/1.3.1/scala/dispatchers.html#Making_the_Actor_mailbox_bounded